# asp.net master property string, how to check in content page if string is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

if i have a master property string for example:

```
public String SharedInfo
{
    get { return (String)Session["SharedInfo"]; }
    set { Session["SharedInfo"] = value; }
}
```

and a label in an content page, i check if the string is empty by doing:
if(Master.SharedInfo == null)

now my question is: why does if(Master.SharedInfo == "") not work, because the SharedInfo is a string right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a handy method that "catches" both

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Master.SharedInfo)) {
    ...
}
```

`null` and `""` are not equal. `null` means no string at all. `""` is a string of length `0`.

```
string s = null;
int i = s.Length; // <-- Throws null reference exception
```

But

```
string s = "";
int i = s.Length; // OK, i => 0
```

`""` and `String.Empty` are equivalent. Some people state that you should always use `String.Empty` instead of `""`, but it makes really no difference.

---

**UPDATE**

Equal string constants are interned by the compiler, i.e. the compiler stores equal constants only once. You can make a simple test (in response to @BobTodd's comment),

```
string s = ""; 
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(s, "")); // --> true
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(s, String.Empty)); // --> true
```

---

For the sake of completeness (according to @JoelEtherton's comment). Starting from .NET Framework 4.0 you can test

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(Master.SharedInfo)) {
    ...
}
```

This will catch strings like `" "` or `"\t"` as well.

Comment: no marked difference just best practice, over using a constant which takes no extra work and "" which creates a new string variable. small, but relevant-ish

Comment: `""` is a constant and is interned by the compiler, i.e. the compiler maintains a pool of string constants (at least within one assembly). `string s = ""; return Object.ReferenceEquals(s, "")` returns `true`. Even this returns `true`, `string s = ""; return Object.ReferenceEquals(s, String.Empty)`.

Answer (score 1):

In c#, an empty string `""` is not null. It's an actual string, with length equals to zero.

You can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(string stringToTest)` to check both null and empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

`String.Empty` ("") and `null` are quite different

It depends wholly on what has been written to Session["SharedInfo"].

If nothing has, then it will be null, otherwise its the value written, which could be an empty string or null.

To be sure use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(string @string)`